# How to infer type from Collection C# Generics

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have this signature of an extension method from the System.IO.BinaryReader class.

```
public static T ReadCollection<T, R>(this BinaryReader reader, Func<BinaryReader, R> serializeItem) where T : ICollection<R>, new() {...}
```

Then I call that method like this

```
IList<User> users = new List<User>();
BinaryReader _reader = new BinaryReader(...);
...
...
 users = _reader.ReadCollection<List<User>, User>(reader => new User
 {
     Id = reader.ReadInt32(),
     Name = reader.ReadString()
 });
```

I wonder if it is possible to call it without specifing the type User twice. *ReadCollection<List<**User**>, **User**>*.
Type arguments cannot be infered from the usage, so I must declare it explicity but Type R will always be the object from the Collection that is already defined.
At the end I'm specifing in the generic type constraint `where T: ICollection<R>`

So the final call should be something like

`_reader.ReadCollection<List<User>>(reader => new User...`

instead of

`_reader.ReadCollection<List<User>, User>(reader => new User...`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about?

    public static T ReadCollection<IEnumerable<T>>(this BinaryReader reader, Func<BinaryReader, T> serializeItem)

Comment: I you want Type parameters to be interfered, all of them must appear as signature parameters.
Either directly or as part of another generic expression that is a parameter.
In your case the T is missing a a parameter.

Comment: You already got good answers, so I'll just explain why you can't "infer the type from the collection type". Imagine what would happen if you passed a class `WeirdList` which implemented *both* `ICollection<A>` and `ICollection<B>`. How would your method know whether to infer `A` or `B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need T at all:

```
public static ICollection<R> ReadCollection<R>(this BinaryReader reader, Func<BinaryReader, R> serializeItem) {...}
```

Or you can add items to any collection in `deserializeItem` delegate:

```
public static void ReadCollection(this BinaryReader reader, Action<BinaryReader> deserializeItem) {...}

var users = new List<User>();
_reader.ReadCollection(reader => users.Add(new User {
   Id = reader.ReadInt32(),
   Name = reader.ReadString()
});
```

Comment: I didn't want to specify new HashSet or new List  `new HashSet<int>(ReadCollection( (reader => ....)` But at the end is the same, declare it explicity so it works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Prefer using most specific type for methods return types (the type you actually construct & return, `List<T>/HashSet<T>`), and most generic types for methods parameters. This will give you most flexibility with calling methods & using their return values.

Answer (score 1):

If you drop the `new()` constraint (though it comes in handy generally) and pass in a factory, that just invokes 'new()' the type parameters can be interfered and omitted on invocation.

`public static T ReadCollection<T, R>(this BinaryReader reader, Func<BinaryReader, R> serializeItem, Func<T> listFactory) where T : ICollection<R> {...}`

In the body of the method `new T()` must be replace by `listFactory()`.

Then you can call it like

`var userList = reader.ReadCollection(reader => new User {..}, () => new List<User>());`

or

`var userList = reader.ReadCollection(reader => new User {..}, () => new HashSet<User>());`